# Telescope - Laravel menu path issue

Tags: php, laravel, telescope

I have installed and configured Laravel Telescope with my Laravel 10 project

**telescope.php**

```
'path' => env('TELESCOPE_PATH', 'telescope')
```

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function register(): void
{
    if ($this->app->environment('local')) {
        $this->app->register(\Laravel\Telescope\TelescopeServiceProvider::class);
        $this->app->register(TelescopeServiceProvider::class);
    }
}
```

When I enter "my-project-path/telescope" in the URL, the dashboard loads perfectly. However, the URLs for all menus (such as "Commands," "Schedule," and "Jobs") redirect to the wrong path.

For example, they go to "http://localhost/telescope/requests" where the project path after "localhost" is missing. It should actually be "http://localhost/my-project/telescope-project/public/telescope/requests." Please guide me on how to configure this correctly.

Please guide me to configure correctly

Comment: what does you APP_URL look like?

Comment: APP_URL=  http://localhost

Comment: set it as http://localhost/my-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I created a blade file at:**

*project_path/resources/views/vendor/telescope/layout.blade.php*

**Then I overrode:**

```
<script>
    window.Telescope = @json($telescopeScriptVariables);
    window.Telescope.path = '{{ url('/') }}';
</script>
```

**layout.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Meta Information -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('/vendor/telescope/favicon.ico') }}">

    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">

    <title>Telescope{{ config('app.name') ? ' - ' . config('app.name') : '' }}</title>

    <!-- Style sheets-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
    <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:300,400,500,600" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{{ asset(mix($cssFile, 'vendor/telescope')) }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="telescope" v-cloak>
    <alert :message="alert.message"
           :type="alert.type"
           :auto-close="alert.autoClose"
           :confirmation-proceed="alert.confirmationProceed"
           :confirmation-cancel="alert.confirmationCancel"
           v-if="alert.type"></alert>

    <div class="container mb-5">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch py-4 header">
            <router-link to="/" class="logo d-flex align-items-center">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 80 80">
                    <path class="fill-primary" d="M0 40a39.87 39.87 0 0 1 11.72-28.28A40 40 0 1 1 0 40zm34 10a4 4 0 0 1-4-4v-2a2 2 0 1 0-4 0v2a4 4 0 0 1-4 4h-2a2 2 0 1 0 0 4h2a4 4 0 0 1 4 4v2a2 2 0 1 0 4 0v-2a4 4 0 0 1 4-4h2a2 2 0 1 0 0-4h-2zm24-24a6 6 0 0 1-6-6v-3a3 3 0 0 0-6 0v3a6 6 0 0 1-6 6h-3a3 3 0 0 0 0 6h3a6 6 0 0 1 6 6v3a3 3 0 0 0 6 0v-3a6 6 0 0 1 6-6h3a3 3 0 0 0 0-6h-3zm-4 36a4 4 0 1 0 0-8 4 4 0 0 0 0 8zM21 28a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z"></path>
                </svg>

                <h4 class="mb-0 ml-3"><strong>Laravel</strong> Telescope{{ config('app.name') ? ' - ' . config('app.name') : '' }}</h4>
            </router-link>

            <button class="btn btn-muted ml-auto mr-3 d-flex align-items-center py-2" v-on:click.prevent="toggleRecording" :title="recording ? 'Pause recording' : 'Resume recording'">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="icon" fill="currentColor" v-if="recording">
                    <path d="M5.75 3a.75.75 0 00-.75.75v12.5c0 .414.336.75.75.75h1.5a.75.75 0 00.75-.75V3.75A.75.75 0 007.25 3h-1.5zM12.75 3a.75.75 0 00-.75.75v12.5c0 .414.336.75.75.75h1.5a.75.75 0 00.75-.75V3.75a.75.75 0 00-.75-.75h-1.5z" />
                </svg>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="icon" fill="currentColor" v-else>
                    <path d="M6.3 2.841A1.5 1.5 0 004 4.11V15.89a1.5 1.5 0 002.3 1.269l9.344-5.89a1.5 1.5 0 000-2.538L6.3 2.84z" />
                </svg>
            </button>

            <button class="btn btn-muted mr-3 d-flex align-items-center py-2" v-on:click.prevent="clearEntries" title="Clear entries">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="icon" fill="currentColor">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8.75 1A2.75 2.75 0 006 3.75v.443c-.795.077-1.584.176-2.365.298a.75.75 0 10.23 1.482l.149-.022.841 10.518A2.75 2.75 0 007.596 19h4.807a2.75 2.75 0 002.742-2.53l.841-10.52.149.023a.75.75 0 00.23-1.482A41.03 41.03 0 0014 4.193V3.75A2.75 2.75 0 0011.25 1h-2.5zM10 4c.84 0 1.673.025 2.5.075V3.75c0-.69-.56-1.25-1.25-1.25h-2.5c-.69 0-1.25.56-1.25 1.25v.325C8.327 4.025 9.16 4 10 4zM8.58 7.72a.75.75 0 00-1.5.06l.3 7.5a.75.75 0 101.5-.06l-.3-7.5zm4.34.06a.75.75 0 10-1.5-.06l-.3 7.5a.75.75 0 101.5.06l.3-7.5z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                </svg>
            </button>

            <button class="btn btn-muted mr-3 d-flex align-items-center py-2" :class="{active: autoLoadsNewEntries}" v-on:click.prevent="autoLoadNewEntries" title="Auto load entries">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="icon" fill="currentColor">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M15.312 11.424a5.5 5.5 0 01-9.201 2.466l-.312-.311h2.433a.75.75 0 000-1.5H3.989a.75.75 0 00-.75.75v4.242a.75.75 0 001.5 0v-2.43l.31.31a7 7 0 0011.712-3.138.75.75 0 00-1.449-.39zm1.23-3.723a.75.75 0 00.219-.53V2.929a.75.75 0 00-1.5 0V5.36l-.31-.31A7 7 0 003.239 8.188a.75.75 0 101.448.389A5.5 5.5 0 0113.89 6.11l.311.31h-2.432a.75.75 0 000 1.5h4.243a.75.75 0 00.53-.219z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                </svg>
            </button>

            <router-link to="/monitored-tags" class="btn btn-muted d-flex align-items-center py-2" title="Monitoring">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="icon" fill="currentColor">
                    <path d="M10 12.5a2.5 2.5 0 100-5 2.5 2.5 0 000 5z" />
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M.664 10.59a1.651 1.651 0 010-1.186A10.004 10.004 0 0110 3c4.257 0 7.893 2.66 9.336 6.41.147.381.146.804 0 1.186A10.004 10.004 0 0110 17c-4.257 0-7.893-2.66-9.336-6.41zM14 10a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                </svg>
            </router-link>
        </div>

        <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col-2 sidebar">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/requests" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.2 2.24a.75.75 0 00.04 1.06l2.1 1.95H6.75a.75.75 0 000 1.5h8.59l-2.1 1.95a.75.75 0 101.02 1.1l3.5-3.25a.75.75 0 000-1.1l-3.5-3.25a.75.75 0 00-1.06.04zm-6.4 8a.75.75 0 00-1.06-.04l-3.5 3.25a.75.75 0 000 1.1l3.5 3.25a.75.75 0 101.02-1.1l-2.1-1.95h8.59a.75.75 0 000-1.5H4.66l2.1-1.95a.75.75 0 00.04-1.06z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                            <span>Requests</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/commands" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.25 3A2.25 2.25 0 001 5.25v9.5A2.25 2.25 0 003.25 17h13.5A2.25 2.25 0 0019 14.75v-9.5A2.25 2.25 0 0016.75 3H3.25zm.943 8.752a.75.75 0 01.055-1.06L6.128 9l-1.88-1.693a.75.75 0 111.004-1.114l2.5 2.25a.75.75 0 010 1.114l-2.5 2.25a.75.75 0 01-1.06-.055zM9.75 10.25a.75.75 0 000 1.5h2.5a.75.75 0 000-1.5h-2.5z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                            <span>Commands</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/schedule" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm.75-13a.75.75 0 00-1.5 0v5c0 .414.336.75.75.75h4a.75.75 0 000-1.5h-3.25V5z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                            <span>Schedule</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/jobs" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path d="M2 4.5A2.5 2.5 0 014.5 2h11a2.5 2.5 0 010 5h-11A2.5 2.5 0 012 4.5zM2.75 9.083a.75.75 0 000 1.5h14.5a.75.75 0 000-1.5H2.75zM2.75 12.663a.75.75 0 000 1.5h14.5a.75.75 0 000-1.5H2.75zM2.75 16.25a.75.75 0 000 1.5h14.5a.75.75 0 100-1.5H2.75z" />
                            </svg>
                            <span>Jobs</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item mt-3">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/batches" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 3.75A.75.75 0 012.75 3h14.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5H2.75A.75.75 0 012 3.75zm0 4.167a.75.75 0 01.75-.75h14.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5H2.75a.75.75 0 01-.75-.75zm0 4.166a.75.75 0 01.75-.75h14.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5H2.75a.75.75 0 01-.75-.75zm0 4.167a.75.75 0 01.75-.75h14.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5H2.75a.75.75 0 01-.75-.75z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                            <span>Batches</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/cache" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.606 12.97a.75.75 0 01-.134 1.051 2.494 2.494 0 00-.93 2.437 2.494 2.494 0 002.437-.93.75.75 0 111.186.918 3.995 3.995 0 01-4.482 1.332.75.75 0 01-.461-.461 3.994 3.994 0 011.332-4.482.75.75 0 011.052.134z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.752 12A13.07 13.07 0 008 14.248v4.002c0 .414.336.75.75.75a5 5 0 004.797-6.414 12.984 12.984 0 005.45-10.848.75.75 0 00-.735-.735 12.984 12.984 0 00-10.849 5.45A5 5 0 001 11.25c.001.414.337.75.751.75h4.002zM13 9a2 2 0 100-4 2 2 0 000 4z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                            <span>Cache</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/dumps" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.25 2A2.25 2.25 0 002 4.25v11.5A2.25 2.25 0 004.25 18h11.5A2.25 2.25 0 0018 15.75V4.25A2.25 2.25 0 0015.75 2H4.25zm4.03 6.28a.75.75 0 00-1.06-1.06L4.97 9.47a.75.75 0 000 1.06l2.25 2.25a.75.75 0 001.06-1.06L6.56 10l1.72-1.72zm4.5-1.06a.75.75 0 10-1.06 1.06L13.44 10l-1.72 1.72a.75.75 0 101.06 1.06l2.25-2.25a.75.75 0 000-1.06l-2.25-2.25z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                            <span>Dumps</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/events" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path d="M13.92 3.845a19.361 19.361 0 01-6.3 1.98C6.765 5.942 5.89 6 5 6a4 4 0 00-.504 7.969 15.974 15.974 0 001.271 3.341c.397.77 1.342 1 2.05.59l.867-.5c.726-.42.94-1.321.588-2.021-.166-.33-.315-.666-.448-1.004 1.8.358 3.511.964 5.096 1.78A17.964 17.964 0 0015 10c0-2.161-.381-4.234-1.08-6.155zM15.243 3.097A19.456 19.456 0 0116.5 10c0 2.431-.445 4.758-1.257 6.904l-.03.077a.75.75 0 001.401.537 20.902 20.902 0 001.312-5.745 1.999 1.999 0 000-3.545 20.902 20.902 0 00-1.312-5.745.75.75 0 00-1.4.537l.029.077z" />
                            </svg>
                            <span>Events</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/exceptions" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.56 1.14a.75.75 0 01.177 1.045 3.989 3.989 0 00-.464.86c.185.17.382.329.59.473A3.993 3.993 0 0110 2c1.272 0 2.405.594 3.137 1.518.208-.144.405-.302.59-.473a3.989 3.989 0 00-.464-.86.75.75 0 011.222-.869c.369.519.65 1.105.822 1.736a.75.75 0 01-.174.707 7.03 7.03 0 01-1.299 1.098A4 4 0 0114 6c0 .52-.301.963-.723 1.187a6.961 6.961 0 01-1.158.486c.13.208.231.436.296.679 1.413-.174 2.779-.5 4.081-.96a19.655 19.655 0 00-.09-2.319.75.75 0 111.493-.146 21.239 21.239 0 01.08 3.028.75.75 0 01-.482.667 20.874 20.874 0 01-5.153 1.249 2.51 2.51 0 01-.107.247 20.86 20.86 0 015.253 1.257.75.75 0 01.48.74 20.946 20.946 0 01-.907 5.107.75.75 0 01-1.433-.444c.415-1.34.69-2.743.806-4.19-.495-.174-1-.328-1.512-.461.05.284.076.575.076.873 0 1.814-.517 3.312-1.426 4.37A4.639 4.639 0 0110 19a4.64 4.64 0 01-3.574-1.63C5.516 16.311 5 14.813 5 13c0-.298.026-.59.076-.873-.513.133-1.017.287-1.512.46.116 1.448.39 2.85.806 4.191a.75.75 0 01-1.433.444 20.94 20.94 0 01-.908-5.107.75.75 0 01.482-.74 20.857 20.857 0 015.252-1.257 2.481 2.481 0 01-.107-.247 20.874 20.874 0 01-5.153-1.249.75.75 0 01-.482-.667 21.342 21.342 0 01.08-3.028.75.75 0 111.493.146 19.745 19.745 0 00-.09 2.32c1.302.459 2.668.785 4.08.959.066-.243.166-.471.297-.679a6.962 6.962 0 01-1.158-.486A1.348 1.348 0 016 6a4 4 0 01.166-1.143 7.032 7.032 0 01-1.3-1.098.75.75 0 01-.173-.707 5.48 5.48 0 01.822-1.736.75.75 0 011.046-.176z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                            <span>Exceptions</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/gates" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 1a4.5 4.5 0 00-4.5 4.5V9H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v6a2 2 0 002 2h10a2 2 0 002-2v-6a2 2 0 00-2-2h-.5V5.5A4.5 4.5 0 0010 1zm3 8V5.5a3 3 0 10-6 0V9h6z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                            <span>Gates</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/client-requests" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 10a8 8 0 11-16 0 8 8 0 0116 0zm-1.5 0a6.5 6.5 0 11-11-4.69v.447a3.5 3.5 0 001.025 2.475L8.293 10 8 10.293a1 1 0 000 1.414l1.06 1.06a1.5 1.5 0 01.44 1.061v.363a1 1 0 00.553.894l.276.139a1 1 0 001.342-.448l1.454-2.908a1.5 1.5 0 00-.281-1.731l-.772-.772a1 1 0 00-1.023-.242l-.384.128a.5.5 0 01-.606-.25l-.296-.592a.481.481 0 01.646-.646l.262.131a1 1 0 00.447.106h.188a1 1 0 00.949-1.316l-.068-.204a.5.5 0 01.149-.538l1.44-1.234A6.492 6.492 0 0116.5 10z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                            <span>HTTP Client</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/logs" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path d="M2 3a1 1 0 00-1 1v1a1 1 0 001 1h16a1 1 0 001-1V4a1 1 0 00-1-1H2z" />
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 7.5h16l-.811 7.71a2 2 0 01-1.99 1.79H4.802a2 2 0 01-1.99-1.79L2 7.5zM7 11a1 1 0 011-1h4a1 1 0 110 2H8a1 1 0 01-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                            <span>Logs</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/mail" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path d="M3 4a2 2 0 00-2 2v1.161l8.441 4.221a1.25 1.25 0 001.118 0L19 7.162V6a2 2 0 00-2-2H3z" />
                                <path d="M19 8.839l-7.77 3.885a2.75 2.75 0 01-2.46 0L1 8.839V14a2 2 0 002 2h14a2 2 0 002-2V8.839z" />
                            </svg>
                            <span>Mail</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/models" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 6a3 3 0 013-3h12a3 3 0 013 3v8a3 3 0 01-3 3H4a3 3 0 01-3-3V6zm4 1.5a2 2 0 114 0 2 2 0 01-4 0zm2 3a4 4 0 00-3.665 2.395.75.75 0 00.416 1A8.98 8.98 0 007 14.5a8.98 8.98 0 003.249-.604.75.75 0 00.416-1.001A4.001 4.001 0 007 10.5zm5-3.75a.75.75 0 01.75-.75h2.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-2.5a.75.75 0 01-.75-.75zm0 6.5a.75.75 0 01.75-.75h2.5a.75.75 0 010 1.5h-2.5a.75.75 0 01-.75-.75zm.75-4a.75.75 0 000 1.5h2.5a.75.75 0 000-1.5h-2.5z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                            <span>Models</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/notifications" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path d="M4.214 3.227a.75.75 0 00-1.156-.956 8.97 8.97 0 00-1.856 3.826.75.75 0 001.466.316 7.47 7.47 0 011.546-3.186zM16.942 2.271a.75.75 0 00-1.157.956 7.47 7.47 0 011.547 3.186.75.75 0 001.466-.316 8.971 8.971 0 00-1.856-3.826z" />
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 2a6 6 0 00-6 6c0 1.887-.454 3.665-1.257 5.234a.75.75 0 00.515 1.076 32.94 32.94 0 003.256.508 3.5 3.5 0 006.972 0 32.933 32.933 0 003.256-.508.75.75 0 00.515-1.076A11.448 11.448 0 0116 8a6 6 0 00-6-6zm0 14.5a2 2 0 01-1.95-1.557 33.54 33.54 0 003.9 0A2 2 0 0110 16.5z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                            <span>Notifications</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/queries" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 1c3.866 0 7 1.79 7 4s-3.134 4-7 4-7-1.79-7-4 3.134-4 7-4zm5.694 8.13c.464-.264.91-.583 1.306-.952V10c0 2.21-3.134 4-7 4s-7-1.79-7-4V8.178c.396.37.842.688 1.306.953C5.838 10.006 7.854 10.5 10 10.5s4.162-.494 5.694-1.37zM3 13.179V15c0 2.21 3.134 4 7 4s7-1.79 7-4v-1.822c-.396.37-.842.688-1.306.953-1.532.875-3.548 1.369-5.694 1.369s-4.162-.494-5.694-1.37A7.009 7.009 0 013 13.179z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                            <span>Queries</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/redis" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path d="M.96 9.84c1.35.61 6.83 2.83 7.73 3.26.93.44 1.58.45 2.75-.16 1.13-.59 6.21-2.68 7.6-3.36l.16.06c1.04.38 1.08.7.01 1.25-1.06.56-6.59 2.83-7.77 3.44-1.17.62-1.82.61-2.75.17-.93-.45-6.81-2.82-7.87-3.33-1.06-.5-1.08-.85-.04-1.26l.18-.07zM.8 13.19h.01c1.06.5 6.94 2.88 7.87 3.33.93.44 1.58.45 2.75-.17 1.17-.6 6.6-2.84 7.74-3.42h.02c1.04.39 1.08.7.01 1.26-1.06.55-6.59 2.82-7.77 3.44-1.17.61-1.82.6-2.75.16-.93-.44-6.81-2.82-7.87-3.33-1.06-.5-1.08-.85-.04-1.26l.03-.01zm18.4-5.71c-1.06.55-6.59 2.82-7.77 3.44-1.17.61-1.82.6-2.75.16-.93-.44-6.81-2.82-7.87-3.32C-.24 7.25-.26 6.9.78 6.49c1.04-.4 6.89-2.7 8.12-3.14 1.24-.44 1.67-.46 2.72-.07 1.05.38 6.54 2.57 7.58 2.95 1.04.38 1.08.7.01 1.25zm-6.59-1.95l-1.34-.5.36-.86-1.32.44-1.4-.55.45.83-1.5.53 2 .18.63 1.04.39-.93 1.73-.18zm-2.22 4.53L11.8 8l-4.63.7 3.23 1.35zm-4.48-2.1c1.37 0 2.47-.42 2.47-.95s-1.1-.96-2.47-.96-2.48.43-2.48.96 1.11.96 2.48.96zm8.75-2.17v2.16l2.74-1.08-2.74-1.08zm-3.03 1.2l2.73 1.08.3-.12V5.8l-3.03 1.2z"></path>
                            </svg>
                            <span>Redis</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <router-link active-class="active" to="/views" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.25 3A2.25 2.25 0 001 5.25v9.5A2.25 2.25 0 003.25 17h13.5A2.25 2.25 0 0019 14.75v-9.5A2.25 2.25 0 0016.75 3H3.25zM2.5 9v5.75c0 .414.336.75.75.75h13.5a.75.75 0 00.75-.75V9h-15zM4 5.25a.75.75 0 00-.75.75v.01c0 .414.336.75.75.75h.01a.75.75 0 00.75-.75V6a.75.75 0 00-.75-.75H4zM6.25 6A.75.75 0 017 5.25h.01a.75.75 0 01.75.75v.01a.75.75 0 01-.75.75H7a.75.75 0 01-.75-.75V6zM10 5.25a.75.75 0 00-.75.75v.01c0 .414.336.75.75.75h.01a.75.75 0 00.75-.75V6a.75.75 0 00-.75-.75H10z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                            </svg>
                            <span>Views</span>
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-10">
                <router-view></router-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    window.Telescope = @json($telescopeScriptVariables);
    window.Telescope.path = '{{ url('/') }}';
</script>

</body>
</html>
```